# Unable to install, system folder path does not appear to be set correctly

Tags: ee2, path

I am experiencing some weird behaviour here. I am installing EE fresh from the zip, no changes, no bootstraps or anything like that. However, the system folder path message keeps showing up. It doesn't really matter what i enter as a var, allways getting the message.
I tried the var as it comes out of the box (./system), i tried a hard-coded server path (/home/pvfonds/public_html/dev/system), and everything else i could think of.

Comment: Hi Jelle, two questions: is this on a remote server or locally? and if you upload and run the [EE server wizard](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html#requirements) does the wizard tell you that your server is compatible with EE's requirements?

Comment: it is on a remote server, and it houses 2 other EE sites. So i know it is compatible with EE's requirements

Comment: Is there an .htaccess file with anything in it that might cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. the server had some setting that set all filenames to lowercase. When this was turned off, everything worked...

Answer (score 1):

More than likely permissions. Drop to a terminal prompt within the site folder and would run the following two commands:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This sets all folders with 755 and all files with 644 recursively. This is the default starting point before you have to set specific permissions for files such as config.php etc.

See how you get in with that.

Comment: All permissions are correct. Ran the commands, and checked manually too. still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run the site in a sub-folder called `/dev`. Are the other sites also running in sub-folders and have you tried running the site just beneath `/public_html`?